# 5-сантиметровый

Tags: нормы-языка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильное написание слова "пятисантиметровый". 
Можно ли писать 5-сантиметровый или 5-ти сантиметровый?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для записи чисел и знаков в тексте разработаны специальные правила
http://diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/6.html#6.2.2

Правильно: 5-сантиметровый

Рекомендуется словесно-цифровая форма (число в цифровой форме и присоединяемое дефисом существительное или прилагательное). Напр.: 150-летие, 20-километровый переход, 25-процентный раствор.
Неверно: 150-тилетие, 20-тикилометровый переход и т. п., т. е. с присоединением ко второй части слова окончания числительного.

ТАКЖЕ ИНТЕРЕСНО

Падежное окончание в порядковых числительных, обозначенных арабскими цифрами, по закрепившейся традиции должно быть:

Однобуквенным, если последней букве числительного предшествует гласный звук. Правильно: 5-й (пятый, пятой), 5-я (пятая), неправильно: 5-ый, 5-ой, 5-ая, 5-ое, 5-ые, 5-ым, 5-ом, 5-ых

Двухбуквенным, если последней букве числительного предшествует согласный. Правильно:5-го, 5-му, 30-ми, неправильно: 5-ого, 5-ому, 30-ыми

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю, что в литературном русском языке числа до десяти включительно лучше писать словами.

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее, последнее. А в случаях, когда терзают сомнения, пишите - "пятисантиметровый".